# In Laravel 5.7 React app, getting the error: 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, laravel-5.7

I'm very new to **React.js**. I installed **Laravel 5.7** and swapped Vue.js scaffolding with React by running this command:

```
php artisan preset react
```

Now the problem is, I cannot assign anything to the state inside a component.

For example if I do the following inside the component:

```
state = { foo: false };
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/Root.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\xampp\htdocs\smart-school-v0.1\resources\js\components\Root.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (8:11):
```

I installed:

```
@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

and updated **.babelrc** (Babel configuration file) like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8577#issuecomment-439579410) but no luck.

**Package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,

    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.13",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
    }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
 {
    "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
 }
```

**Root.js Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Root extends Component {

    state = { foo: false };

    render() {

        return (
        <p>Loaded</p>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

It is not working as expected and I'm keep getting this error:

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError: D:\xampp\htdocs\smart-school-v0.1\resources\js\components\Root.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (19:11):

17 |
18 |
> 19 |     state = { foo: false };
    |           ^
20 |
21 |     render() {
22 |

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.


@ ./resources/js/app.js 14:0-28
@ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
                                                                                                                                                                                            Asset     Size   Chunks
    Chunk Names
/css/app.css  0 bytes  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
/js/app.js  593 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/js/components/Root.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\xampp\htdocs\smart-school-v0.1\resources\js\components\Root.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (19:11):
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I had a similar issue. Your post helped me to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @dns_nx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Cretae .babelrc file in root folder.
2. Write in .babelrc:

> { "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] }

3. Run npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
4. Run npm run dev

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you for your time to write this answer its clear and solve my problem

Answer (score 29):

I just tested on Laravel Framework 5.7.19 and the following steps work:

1. Make sure your `.babelrc` file is in the root folder of your application, and add the following code:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

2. Run `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`.
3. Run `npm run watch`.

Comment: It is not working in my case. I created a .bablerc file on the root directory but the strange thing is, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: It Worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Simple Add this to your

**package.json**

```
"babel": {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: It gives error `Unknown plugin "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" specified`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply

1. create ***.babelrc*** file and paste this code in your ***.babelrc*** file
   `{  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]  }`
2. and now run `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-proper`
3. and finally run `npm run watch`

done

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines to your **Package.json** file:

```
"babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    }
```